# Passing Int to dynamic stored procedure fails

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a dynamic stored procedure in SQL Server that works well to pivot a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DynamicPivotTableInSql
    @ColumnToPivot  NVARCHAR(255),
    @ListToPivot    NVARCHAR(255),
    @SurveyID           INT=10
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlStatement = N'SELECT * 
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT
                                   [resp_id], [benefit], [weight]
                               FROM Segment_Responses) myResults
                          PIVOT 
                              (SUM([weight])
                                   FOR [' + @ColumnToPivot + ']
                                   IN (' + @ListToPivot + ')) AS PivotTable';
 
    EXEC (@SqlStatement)
END
```

and I call it like this

```
EXEC DynamicPivotTableInSql 
         @ColumnToPivot = 'benefit',
         @ListToPivot = '[OBSERVABILITY], [COST], [EASE OF USE], [SERVICE]'
```

Here is where I run into problems. You'll notice I have hardcoded `@SurveyID = 10` and if I try to add that as a where statement in the stored procedure like this:

```
FROM Segment_Responses 
WHERE survey_id = ' + @SurveyID + '
```

and run the stored procedure again I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '
> SELECT * FROM (
> SELECT
> [resp_id],
> [benefit],
> [weight]
> FROM Segment_Responses where survey_id=' to data type int.

I've tried to solve this many ways (e.g., passed the Int variable instead of hard coding it) but always get the same result. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Side note: SQL injection alert. Instead of passing a comma separated string for the list of columns, use a table variable and use `quotename()` on the column names, as well as on the table name before concatenating them to the query. Also, there's an extra datatype for identifiers, `sysname`, that you should use for them.

Comment: no risk of injection since I'm the person who uses this..but thanks for the reminder

Comment: ... until you aren't. And a bad excuse for bad practice anyway.

Comment: Why write code the way you know is wrong in the first place, when the error you got can't happen if you parametrise in the first place, @Allen ?

Comment: That (risk of SQL injection) was my first thought as well, @stickybit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` only works with strings.  If you use a number TSQL assumes you are trying to use the addition operator, and tries to convert the string argument to int.

eg this

```
select 1 + '2'
```

works and returns 3.

Use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of `+`, or use an [explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the int.

eg

```
WHERE survey_id = ' + cast(@SurveyID as varchar(20)) + '
```

Comment: ok..I tried making it survey_id='@SurveyID' but then I get an error when trying to save the procedure

Comment: Thanks...that did it...didn't realize I had to convert to a string since its an integer in the database...anyway..that helped...thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is why the syntax `EXEC (@SQL)` is strongly suggested against. Use `sys.sp_executesql` and parametrise your statement:

```sql
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE survey_id = @SurveyID ...;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SurveyID int',SurveyID;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to try to add some clarity, when you add together two different types, SQL Server will (where it can) implicitly convert one to the other - the result must be a single type after all.

It decides which one to convert "to the other" based on an [order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).

So where you are trying to concatenate a *varchar* with an *int*, the *int* has the higher order of precedence. This is also a common cause of errors and bugs when using a *case expression* when mixing types in different execution paths of the expression.

You need to be explicit and cast the int to a *varchar*.

Ideally you would use a *parameterised query* which would also reuse the cached execution plan - this may be beneficial if the cardinality of the data is similar but sometimes making the value part of the query dynamically can be advantagous, it depends on the use-case.